# A Rails Validation is Not Allowing A Record to Insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this validation in my model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :micro_id, :conditions => ["date_active not null and date_inactive null"]
```

I interpret this as: okay to insert if this is the only record where the micro_id is 2695 AND  date_active is not null AND date_inactive is null.

In the database, for micro_id 2695, I have one record: It has a date_active and a date_inactive.  I should be able to insert a new record for 2695 when I have a date_active and a null date_inactive.  But, I cannot insert a record.  I've determined this is the validation that is causing the validation error.

Am I interpreting this validation incorrectly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are slightly off, you have `date_active not null and date_inactive null` where you should be testing for null with `is not` and `is` such as `date_active is not null and date_inactive is null`. This makes your validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :micro_id, :conditions => ["date_active is not null and date_inactive is null"]
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you Izuriel.  I thought I had learned that by an example, but I probably got it wrong.  Cheers!

Comment: @JohnCowan No worries, testing for `NULL` is not like testing for other values in SQL, it kind of irks my OCD. I'd rather do `column = NULL` just like I do for other values but alas :P